# How do I grant my azure pipeline permission to publish an azure artifact?

Tags: azure-devops

I have created an azure pipeline that should publish an artifact.

```yaml
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - '*'
      
variables:
  - name: PackageName
    value: 'Netizen.Configuration'
  - name: Version
    value: # Determined by tag on repo

steps:
  - checkout: self

  # Extract tag name and set it as Version
  - powershell: |
      $tag = "$(Build.SourceBranch)".Replace("refs/tags/", "")
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]$tag"
    displayName: 'Get tag version'
    condition: startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')
    
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Version is '$(Version)'"
    displayName: 'Print Version'

  - task: gitversion/setup@0
    displayName: 'Installing GitVersion'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '5.x'
  
  - task: gitversion/execute@0
    displayName: 'Running GitVersion'
    inputs:
      additionalArguments: '/updateprojectfiles'

  - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
    displayName: 'Authenticating NuGet'
  
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restoring packages'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: '8c97****-****-****-****-********4bdd/1366****-****-****-****-********6d5d'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.sln'
      arguments: '--no-restore'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
      testRunTitle: 'Running tests'
      nobuild: true

  # Conditional Pack Step when Version is set
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Version'], ''), ne(variables['Version'], 'undefined'))
    displayName: 'Creating package'
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: '**/$(PackageName).csproj'
      includesymbols: true
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      buildProperties: 'Version=$(Version)'

  # Conditional Publish Step when Version is set  
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Version'], ''), ne(variables['Version'], 'undefined'))
    displayName: 'Publishing package'
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: '8c97****-****-****-****-********4bdd/1366****-****-****-****-********6d5d'
```

This all works as far as the last "Publishing package" step `NuGetCommand@2`.

This is the error output.

```
[CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Matched prefix: https://mrpmorris.pkgs.visualstudio.com/
[CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint https://mrpmorris.pkgs.visualstudio.com/GUID1/_packaging/GUID2/nuget/v3/index.json
[CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 23
[CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 28
Pushing Netizen.Configuration.0.0.2.nupkg to 'https://mrpmorris.pkgs.visualstudio.com/GUID1/_packaging/GUID2/nuget/v2/'...
  PUT https://mrpmorris.pkgs.visualstudio.com/GUID1/_packaging/GUID2/nuget/v2/
  Forbidden https://mrpmorris.pkgs.visualstudio.com/GUID1/_packaging/GUID2/nuget/v2/ 38ms
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User 'GUID3' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: GUID4)).
  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () [0x00040] in <dec5519efdf9482fbfb76832fbc71b94>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource+<>c.<PushPackageToServer>b__23_0 (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response) [0x00000] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.ProcessResponseAsync[T] (NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceRequest request, System.Func`2[T,TResult] processAsync, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000f5] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.PushPackageToServer (System.String source, System.String apiKey, System.String pathToPackage, System.Int64 packageSize, System.Boolean noServiceEndpoint, System.TimeSpan requestTimeout, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00408] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.PushPackageCore (System.String source, System.String apiKey, System.String packageToPush, System.Boolean noServiceEndpoint, System.TimeSpan requestTimeout, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, System.Boolean isSnupkgPush) [0x00176] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.PushPackage (System.String packagePath, System.String source, System.String apiKey, System.Boolean noServiceEndpoint, System.TimeSpan requestTimeout, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, System.Boolean isSnupkgPush) [0x00124] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.Push (System.String packagePath, System.String symbolSource, System.Int32 timeoutInSecond, System.Boolean disableBuffering, System.Func`2[T,TResult] getApiKey, System.Func`2[T,TResult] getSymbolApiKey, System.Boolean noServiceEndpoint, NuGet Protocol.Core.Types.SymbolPackageUpdateResourceV3 symbolPackageUpdateResource, NuGet.Common.ILogger log) [0x00107] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.Run (NuGet.Configuration.ISettings settings, NuGet.Configuration.IPackageSourceProvider sourceProvider, System.String packagePath, System.String source, System.String apiKey, System.String symbolSource, System.String symbolApiKey, System.Int32 timeoutSeconds, System.Boolean disableBuffering, System.Boolean noSymbols, System.Boolean noServiceEndpoint, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger) [0x002f3] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.PushCommand.ExecuteCommandAsync () [0x0016d] in <dc1b484fc03b4c9e94db6d2032a7a13d>:0 
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User 'GUID3' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: GUID4)).)
##[error]Packages failed to publish
Finishing: Publishing package
```

How can I fix this?

Update, I have granted the following permissions to the feed, but without success.

[image: Feed permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. Go to "**Organization Settings**" > under "**Pipelines**" > "**Settings**", disable the following options. Also check same options on "**Project Settings**".

   - **`Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`**
   - **`Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines`**

   [image]
2. Like as you have done, add the following identities with the '**Contributor**' role at least in the Azure Artifacts feed.

   - **`Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})`**
   - **`{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})`**
3. Recreate a new pipeline with the same YAML file.
4. You also can try to change from the **`NuGetCommand@2`** task to **`DotNetCoreCLI@2`** task to run the '[**`dotnet nuget push`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push)' command to push the package.

---

Comment: I was not using `Contributor` as my role. Thank you!